# HTTP-404 with cxf-rs and spring integration

Tags: spring, rest, jax-rs, cxf, web.xml

I am new to web services development. Trying to build a basic restfull webservice using apache-cxf with spring integration. But when I try to access the rest resource uri, http-404 is coming. Following are the files which may have problem:

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>RestDemo</display-name>
    <description>RestDemo</description>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>springrest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**springrest-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sohel.resource" />
```

**MessageResource.java**

```
@Path("/messages")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)


public class MessageResource {

    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();

    @GET
public List<Message> getMessages(@BeanParam MessageFilterBean filterBean) {

    if (filterBean.getYear() > 0) {
        return messageService.getAllMessagesForYear(filterBean.getYear());
    }
    if (filterBean.getStart() >= 0 && filterBean.getSize() > 0) {
        return messageService.getAllMessagesPaginated(filterBean.getStart(), filterBean.getSize());
    }
    return messageService.getAllMessages();
}
```

The uri which I am trying to access http://localhost:8080/CopyOfGood/webapi/messages

Comment: The java apis work fine without spring integration. Checked with Jersey as well as cxf. Proper response can be retreived. Problem is only with spring integration.

Comment: Problem still not solved..:(..

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jaxrs server and serviceBeans configuration in the `springrest-servlet.xml`. Checkout  the `beans.xml` file in this [apache cxf docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSservicesincontainerwithSpringconfigurationfile.) which has information on how to configure the server and the serviceBeans.

Comment: I added below two lines. But same problem. <jaxrs:server id="messageResource" address="/test">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           <ref bean="messageBean"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
       
    <bean id="messageBean" class="com.sohel.resource.MessageResource"/>

Comment: since you mentioned the `address` as `/test`, you need to test the url `http://localhost:8080/CopyOfGood/webapi/test/messages`

Comment: or just specify `address="/"` and then test the url `http://localhost:8080/CopyOfGood/webapi/messages`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/CopyOfGood/webapi/messages  This is what I am trying to access

Comment: Did u change the address to `/` instead of `test`? `<jaxrs:server id="messageResource" address="/"> <jaxrs:serviceBeans> <ref bean="messageBean"/> </jaxrs:serviceBeans> </jaxrs:server> <bean id="messageBean" class="com.sohel.resource.MessageResource"/> `

Comment: Added to github     https://github.com/musaddique/spring-rest   @TimeTravel: if you can have a look at the service class, web.xml and spring-rest .xml